# when I try to view my pdf document uploaded to a database in bin format it comes up blank?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, model-view-controller, pdo

I am working on a website using php and mysql, where I save the pdf documents in the database in bin format.

[image]

to be able to see in a viewer the pdf inside a modal window I have this js controller:

```
// Ver el documento
function documento(id_aval) {
    // Crea un objeto que contenga el id_aval
    var dataToSend = { id_aval: id_aval };

    // Realiza una petición AJAX para obtener el documento en formato binario desde el servidor
    $.post("../controllers/Utils/endorsement.php?pc=obtener_documento", dataToSend, function (data) {

        console.log(data)

        // Muestra el PDF en el visor
        mostrarPDF(data);


    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        console.error("Error al obtener el documento:", error);
    });
}

// Función para mostrar el PDF en el visor
function mostrarPDF(data) {
    // Abre el modal
    abrir_view_document();

    // Decodifica la cadena base64 directamente en un Uint8Array
    var decodedPdfData = new Uint8Array([...data].map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));

    // Convierte los datos a base64 nuevamente
    var base64Data = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, decodedPdfData));

    console.log("Base64 Data:", base64Data);

    // Actualiza el contenido del visor de PDF dentro del modal
    var viewer = document.getElementById('ver_documento_contenedor');
    viewer.innerHTML = '<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64Data + '" width="800px" height="500px"></iframe>';

}
```

attached is a screenshot of the logs showing that I get correctly the bin file and the base64 transformation.

[image]
[image]

I also have this php controller:

```php
    // Obtener el documento en formato binario
    case "obtener_documento":
        if (!empty($_POST["id_aval"])) {
            $id_aval = $_POST["id_aval"];
            $documento = $aval->get_documento($id_aval);

            // Devolver el documento en formato binario
            header('Content-type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="documento.pdf"');
            echo $documento;
            exit;
        }
        break;
```

and this php model:

```php
    // Obtener el documento en formato binario
    public function get_documento($id_aval)
    {
        $conectar = parent::conexion();

        $sql = "SELECT documento_avalOrganizacion FROM pc_aval_organizacion WHERE id_aval = ?";
        $stmt = $conectar->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $id_aval);
        $stmt->execute();

        $resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($resultado) {
            return $resultado['documento_avalOrganizacion'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

this is the result i get... the document is blank.

[image]

Neither gives me console errors or logs and the document as such in bin format is not corrupt or anything, in fact if I download it and change the extension from .bin to .pdf you can see the content perfectly.

I do not know if maybe the problem is because I have my page with friendly routes because I tried to do the pdf viewer with a url for the file but always sent me to 404 because it was an undefined path. with everything I also leave my friendly routes code in case it was that ....

.htaccess

```
# Permitir el acceso directo a recursos (CSS, JS, imágenes, etc.)
RewriteRule ^(assets/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

# Permitir el acceso directo a archivos PDF
RewriteRule \.pdf$ - [L]

# Redirigir todas las solicitudes a index.php, excepto para recursos
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Plataforma/

Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 405 /Plataforma/index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /Plataforma/index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /Plataforma/index.php
ErrorDocument 402 /Plataforma/index.php
ErrorDocument 401 /Plataforma/index.php
ErrorDocument 400 /Plataforma/index.php

# log PHP errors to a file
php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_reporting 32767
php_value error_log "error_log.txt"
```

index.php

```php
<?php
// Conexión BDD
require_once 'configs/connections/connection.php';
// Temporizador de la session
require_once 'configs/global/session_timeout.php';

// Obtener la URL solicitada
$folderPath = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];             //Esta ruta es para produccion
$url = substr($request_uri, strlen($folderPath));   //Esta ruta es para local


// Incluir archivos de rutas específicos
require_once 'configs/routes/user.php';
require_once 'configs/routes/admin.php';
require_once 'configs/routes/control.php';


// Definir un array de rutas amigables
$routes = [];

// Agregar las rutas de usuario al array $routes
foreach ($userRoutes as $key => $value) {
    $routes[$key] = $value;
}

// Agregar las rutas de administrador al array $routes
foreach ($adminRoutes as $key => $value) {
    $routes[$key] = $value;
}

// Agregar las rutas de control al array $routes
foreach ($controlRoutes as $key => $value) {
    $routes[$key] = $value;
}


// Comprobar si la ruta solicitada está en el array
if (array_key_exists($url, $routes) && strpos($url, '.pdf') === false && !preg_match('/^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$/', $url)) {
    // Incluir la vista correspondiente
    include $routes[$url];
} else {
    // Ruta no encontrada, mostrar la página de error 404
    include 'views/Error/404/index.php';
}
```

Rutas

```php
<?php
// Variables
$Home_admin         = 'Admin';
$Login_admin        = 'administrador';
$Users              = 'Admin/usuarios';
$User_massive       = 'Admin/usuarios/masivo';
$Organizations      = 'Admin/organizaciones';

$Countries          = 'Admin/paises';
$Type_organization  = 'Admin/organizaciones/tipos';
$Categories         = 'Admin/categorias';
$Type_course        = 'Admin/cursos/tipos';

$Courses            = 'Admin/cursos';
$Students           = 'Admin/cursos/alumnos';
$Endorsements       = 'Admin/avales';
$Certificates       = 'Admin/plantillas/certificados';
$Constancias        = 'Admin/plantillas/constancias';

$Certify            = 'Admin/certificar';


// Designacion de rutas
$adminRoutes = [
    '/' . $Home_admin           => 'views/Admin/Home/index.php',
    '/' . $Login_admin          => 'views/Auth/Admin/index.php',
    '/' . $Users                => 'views/Admin/Utils/Users/index.php',
    '/' . $User_massive         => 'views/Admin/Utils/Users/Massive/index.php',
    '/' . $Organizations        => 'views/Admin/Utils/Organizations/index.php',
    '/' . $Countries            => 'views/Admin/Utils/Countries/index.php',
    '/' . $Type_organization    => 'views/Admin/Utils/Type_organizations/index.php',
    '/' . $Categories           => 'views/Admin/Utils/Categories/index.php',
    '/' . $Type_course          => 'views/Admin/Utils/Type_course/index.php',
    '/' . $Courses              => 'views/Admin/Utils/Course/index.php',
    '/' . $Students             => 'views/Admin/Utils/Course/Student/index.php',
    '/' . $Endorsements         => 'views/Admin/Utils/Endorsement/index.php',
    '/' . $Certificates         => 'views/Admin/Utils/Templates/Certificates/index.php',
    '/' . $Constancias          => 'views/Admin/Utils/Templates/Constancias/index.php',
    '/' . $Certify              => 'views/Admin/Utils/Certify/index.php',
];
```

if you can help me to see what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it, I have been doing it for a long time and I can't find a solution.

Comment: Do you really need to use the POST method? You could use a GET and directy point the `<iframe>` to the URL that generates the PDF.

Comment: As per [ask] please post code as text, not images. Images are useful for screenshots

Comment: Thank you for your answers @ADyson. I have already edited the question, I apologize...

Comment: @Oliver if i need to send the post method the get does not get me the data

Comment: I solved the problem by uploading the file to base64 directly in the database, I guess something went wrong with the bin to base64 conversion so I'll leave it like that, thanks.

Comment: replace mostrarPDF by :

    function mostrarPDF(data) {
        abrir_view_document();
    
        var decodedPdfData = new Uint8Array([...data].map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
        var blob = new Blob([decodedPdfData], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    
        var viewer = document.getElementById('ver_documento_contenedor');
        viewer.innerHTML = '<iframe src="' + url + '" width="800px" height="500px"></iframe>';
    }